# What does Python string.maketrans("","") do?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, punctuation

```
 string.maketrans("","")
```

gives

```
 \x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13 
 \x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
 @ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
 \x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90
\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2
\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4
\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9
\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde
\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed
\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff
```

What does this mean?

And how does it help in removing punctuation in a string with the following call:

```
 import string
 myStr.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans)?

Comment: yes, but how does that big mess from maketrans help us get rid of punctuation?

Comment: @lars: It provides a table to feed the `translate()` method that doesn't do anything (so you can pass the method's second argument and have it only remove characters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll take some liberties, since Python 2 muddles the line being strings and bytes. There are 256 bytes, ranging from 0 to 255. You can get their byte representation by using `chr()`. So, all the bytes from 0 to 255 look like this

```
>>> ''.join(map(chr, range(256)))
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\
x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;
<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80
\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93
\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6
\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9
\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc
\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf
\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2
\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

[`string.maketrans(from, to)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) creates a string of 256 characters, where the characters in `from` will be replaced by `to`. For example, `string.maketrans('ab01', 'AB89')` will return the string from above, but `a` will be replaced by `A`, `b` by `B`, `0` by `8` and `1` by `9`.

```
>>> string.maketrans('ab01', 'AB89')
'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\
x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./8923456789:;
<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`ABcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\x7f\x80
\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93
\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6
\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9
\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc
\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf
\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2
\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
```

Effectively, `string.maketrans('', '') == ''.join(map(chr, range(256)))`.

This serves as a map, which when provided to [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate), it can be used to replace multiple characters with one pass over your string. For the example map above, all characters will remain the same, except from all `a` turning into `A`, `b` into `B`, etc. If you do `myStr.translate(string.maketrans('', ''))`, you simply don't change anything in `myStr`.

Finally, `translate()` has one additional argument, `deletechars`. If you pass a string for that argument, `translate()` will translate all characters according to the mapping you provide, but it will ignore, any characters in `deletechars`. So, putting it all together, `myStr.translate(string.maketrans('', ''), string.punctuation)` does not change any character in the string, but in the process will ignore any character in `string.punctuation`. Effectively, you have removed the punctuation in the output string.

Answer (score 0):

`string.maketrans(intab, outtab)`returns a translation table that maps each character in the intabstring into the character at the same position in the outtab string.

```
tran_table = string.maketrans(intab, outtab)
print myStr.translate(tran_table)
```

The code above will then translate `myStr` using your created table. In your case the table generates all characters because you do not specify anything.

Comment: In Python version 2.6+, you can just use `None` for the _table_ argument and avoid having the need to create the identity translation table.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7's [string.maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) returns a byte value, like your result, which could be used with [string.translate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

`string.translate(s, table)` translates characters in `s` (Let's call this `c`) into `table[ord(c)]`. So `\x00` is translated into `table[0]`, and so on. In your case, it's just returning an identity table.

It should be noted that `string.translate` is deprecated in Python 2.7, and in Python 3.1 and onwards, they are replaced by `bytes.maketrans()`, `bytes.translate()`, and the corresponding methods for `str` ans `bytearray`.

Comment: Note, even in Python 2, `string.translate` is pointless; `str.translate` (a method of all `str` objects) is faster and requires no imports (though `string.maketrans` still does, until Python 3).